Выбор максимального значения SQL запрос
В таблице два столбца: title и data. В title записывается 2 значения sch_N и sch_D. В data данные.
Можно ли вытянуть одним запросом максимальное значение по data по двум условиям. Например: sch_N:=100  sch_D:=200? (100 и 200 максимальные значения).
Пробовал:
SELECT MAX(`data`) 
FROM `all_data_sch` 
WHERE  `title`= 'sch_D' AND `title`= 'sch_N' 

Не получается. Может кто-то сможет подсказать?

как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?

и уточните с помощью меток - какая именно реализация sql вам нужна. что-то не верится, что вам требуется решение на (не существующей в живой природе) реализации ansi sql.

записываеться 2 значения sch_N и sch_N. o_O А в чём разница? WHERE  title= 'sch_D' AND title= 'sch_N' Вы правда хотите найти запись, в которой значение одного поля равно двум РАЗНЫМ значениям одновременно?

@Akina Ну, явные описки я поправил. Так то у автора то sch_N, то sch_B, то sch_D было....

А группировке ещё не учили?
SELECT `title`, MAX(`data`)
FROM `all_data_sch`
WHERE `title` IN ('sch_D', 'sch_N')
-- или WHERE `title` = 'sch_D' OR `title` = 'sch_N'
GROUP BY `title`;

А если значений title всего два, то и WHERE не нужен.

Вот тако решение:
SELECT 'sch_D', MAX(`data`) 
FROM `all_data_sch` 
WHERE  `title`= 'sch_D' 

UNION 

SELECT 'sch_N', MAX(`data`) 
FROM `all_data_sch` 
WHERE  `title`= 'sch_N'

Всех Благодарю.

Ну бред же бредовый...

@Akina Решение, конечно, нарушает принцип DRY, но вроде же рабочее, или я чего-то не понимаю? ))  Если автор вопроса ещё не проходил группировку, но проходил объединение, то нормальный вариант )

@CrazyElf Автору нужно максимальное значение. Одну запись. Если верить тому, что написано в вопросе. Тогда как решение в общем случае вернёт две записи.

@Akina А, ну если так... То, как изъясняется автор, оставляет неоднозначность. Я не уверен, нужно ему одно значение или два - отдельно по каждому title.
